# generate password for auth-plug for mosquitto in c#

Tags: cryptography, mqtt, mosquitto

I have spent all day trying to make a usable pbkdf2 password for the mosquitto-auth-plug.  This program sets it up exactly the way it should be stored in the mysql database.  I have a password hash generated by the program that comes with auth-plug and mosquitto loves it.  I just can't replicate it in c#, if anyone can help please let me know.

```
public string CreatePasswordHash(string password)
    {

        var salt = GenerateRandomSalt();    
        var iterationCount = GetIterationCount();
        var hashValue = GenerateHashValue(password, salt, iterationCount);
        string result = "PBKDF2$sha256$" + iterationCount + "$" + Convert.ToBase64String(salt) + "$" + Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue);
        return result;

    }

    private int GetIterationCount()
    {
        return 901;
    }

    private static byte[] GenerateRandomSalt()
    {
        var csprng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        var salt = new byte[SaltByteLength];
        csprng.GetBytes(salt);
        return salt;
        //return GetLetter();
    }

    private static byte[] GenerateHashValue(string password, byte[] salt, int iterationCount)
    {
         byte[] hashValue;
         var valueToHash = string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) ? string.Empty : password;
         using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(valueToHash, salt, iterationCount))
         {
             hashValue = pbkdf2.GetBytes(DerivedKeyLength);
         }
        return hashValue;


    }
```

---EDIT-----

Rfc2898DeriveBytes states --
Implements password-based key derivation functionality, PBKDF2, by using psuedo-random number generator based on HMACSHA1.

The program/auth-plug seems to be using sha256 is there a c# PBKDF2 that uses this.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. You do have an external program (not shown in the question) which creates a PBKDF2 hash from a password and stores the hash in the db. Then you get a password from a user and try to create the same hash as in the database (via the code you posted above). Die I  understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes the auth-plugin for mosquitto mqtt broker has it's own password checking function that is supposed to use PBKDF2.  I have a program from them that creates a hash that I manually put in the database and it works.  However when I try to duplicate the process in c# my hash isn't correct.  Their program is in c and I need my users to be able to create/change their password in a mobile app written in c#

Comment: Link to the plug in if that helps .... https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears there really wasn't an answer and there weren't many who had tried.  I figured out the problem and after contacting the mosquitto-auth-plug author he felt it would be good for us to add my solution to his contrib folder on the plugins github repo.

So now if you need a c# hashing algorithm for mosquitto-auth-plug just go to the repo in git here

https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug/tree/master/contrib/C%23

and follow my instructions --- Let me know if you have any problems

Answer (score 0):

As you have already stated in your edit, the problem appears to be the difference in hash functions used between the mosquitto plugin (which only supports SHA-256, according to the source code) and the .NET implementation (which can only do SHA-1).

A more flexible implementation of PBKDF2 is available in [BouncyCastle](http://bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html), a more lightweight implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/therealmagicmike/PBKDF2.NET). If you are not satisfied with those two, you could chose to implemnt PBKDF2 yourself, which [is not really hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2#Key_derivation_process).